# Unbuffered queries error - how to get them on localhost

Tags: php, mysql

Sometimes I'm getting this error (on remote server only):

```
General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll()...
```

I added this line on top of my php code - without success:

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute;
```

Two questions:

- How to properly avoid this error, if possible without using `fetchAll()`?
- What should I do to get this error on my localhost, if the error exists?

I'm on Windows 7, xampp, phpmyadmin...

**here is the code**

```
$st = $db->query("select title from folders where id = " . $_GET['fd'] . " limit 1");
$st->execute();
$title = $st->fetchColumn();
$stb = $db->query("select * from arts where folder = " . $_GET['fd'] . " order by ind asc");
```

error is on the last line

Comment: What version of MySQL is being used and is it the same on both servers? Have you compared the MySQL settings to see if there are differences?

Comment: @Dave, my pma is `Version information: 4.8.5`, on remote - `Version information: 4.8.3`, can't see any diff with db settings. I suppose the problem is on `php` side.

Comment: Can you share the code that is being used when the error gets thrown?

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow more than one query to be executed.You have executed a query and it didn't fetch all the results, then you try to execute a second query.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou, how to set this logic on localhost also?

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: @Dave, I updated the post with code

Comment: @MariosNikolaou,  I updated the post with code

Comment: @qadenza - open a second connection that is not buffered.  Or do your other queries outside of the buffered queries execution.  Basically that connection is waiting to pull more records (because its unbuffered and thats how it works) So until it's done your connection is tied into that Query's result set.  The whole point of Unbuffered queries is to pull part of a result set, until your done your interacting with that one result set.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, I understand, but cannot control this things if it appears on remote server only. I would like to get it on localhost also, if possible

Comment: Why are you using Non-buffered queries?  They are only useful for large datasets, I mean millions of rows.  The one I mentioned in my answer was `~ 60GB` of data.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, that's a new info for me. My main reason is - to keep memory free, because of performances. Queries are max 20000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer

1. Create a new (additional) connection.

Once your in the middle of an un-buffered request that connection is locked/block up.  Pretty much unusable.

2. Or don't do it (while the buffered query is on-going).

So if you need to query other things, either do that before the unbuffered part, or open a second buffered (normal) connection to the DB.

I once pulled 140 million rows out of the DB with an un-buffered query.  Now they are in MongoDB (even though I have mixed feelings about this).  PS. if anyone knows how to improve mongo's count performance I am all ears.

You only really need `un-buffered query` if your working with a Large dataset, and I mean > 500k rows.  I use it as a last resort.

Anyway, good luck.  It's a pain.

**Update**

For you case, you need to make the PDOStatement object go away or call `PDOStatement::closeCursor`.

```
$st = $db->query("select title from folders where id = " . $_GET['fd'] . " limit 1");
$st->execute();
$title = $st->fetchColumn();
unset($st); //<---- unset the statement object

$stb = $db->query("select * from arts where folder = " . $_GET['fd'] . " order by ind asc");
```

If I am thinking about it right, that `unset` should take care of it.  Normally this happens when it goes out of scope such as the end of a method or function and no reference to it.  This is sort of like `free_result` or whatever it was for Mysqli

I just assumed you had something like this:

```
$st = $db->query("select title from folders where id = " . $_GET['fd'] . " limit 1");
$st->execute();
foreach($st->fetchColumn() as $col){
     $stb = $db->query("select * from arts where folder = {$col} order by ind asc"); 
}
```

Where you were using the results of an open Query for a new query.  Which is a no-no.  In a case like above the only thing you can do is open a new connection for the part in the loop as it may not be possible to do it all in one Query (for whatever reason).

In any case change this to proper prepared statements:

```
$st = $db->prepare("select title from folders where id = :id limit 1");
$st->execute(['id' => $_GET['fd']]);
```

As it is your vulnerable to SQLInjection.  It's very easy to fix in PDO, and it's very bad to not do it.

Cheers!

Comment: it works, that is called - `a solution`. thanks a lot